# Monitorando banco de dados MySQL c/ aplicação Java

Tags: java, mysql, web-service, hibernate, rest

Eu tenho uma aplicação Java desktop c/ DB MySQL rodando em 100 filiais da empresa a mais de 6 anos. Hoje na matriz precisamos de algumas informações do banco de dados das filiais. Estou desenvolvendo um web service Rest, para realizar essa integração.

A primeira vez que acontecer essa integração, a aplicação desktop vai enviar todos os registros de 3 tabelas diferentes (em média vai ser algo em torno de uns 3000 registros por filiais). Ainda estou verificando a melhor maneira de realizar este bulk insert para não ficar tão pesada as transações.

Depois disso, apenas 1 vez ao dia as filiais vão enviar p/ o WS apenas as novas alterações e novos registros dessas 3 tabelas.

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de realizar um monitoramento desse tipo, quando acontece qualquer mudança no banco de dados, mais específico essas 3 tabelas?

Ou se devo implementar alguma rotina para que tudo que for inserido, alterado ou removido, eu crie um arquivo na pasta da aplicação, e quando realizar o login no aplicativo desktop, enviar esse arquivo p/ o WS consumir e depois deletar este arquivo?

Estou meio perdido, pesquisando bastante e não encontrei nada ainda que seja uma melhor opção para este meu caso.

Valeu galera

---

> ***Estou pesquisando agora algo como um sistema de auditoria, andei lendo
>   sobre o Hibernate Envers e também estive pesquisando sobre Broadcast.
>   Estou analisando e verificando se isso possa ser um caminho para solucionar este caso em particular. Alguém já trabalhou ou conhece essas "possíveis" soluções?***

---

> ***Estou realizando alguns testes, ainda em rede mesmo, e pegando outros
>   micros para simular como se fosse filiais da empresa, claro que ainda
>   esta longe do cenário real, mas só para ter uma idéia. Além do JMeter,
>   existe alguma outra tecnologia para realizar estes tipos de testes?***

Comment: Galera fiz um post maneiro sobre Hibernate Envers, lá eu ensino como customizar a auditoria de ações do hibernate e como consumir os dados gerados nessas tabelas de auditoria do envers por meio de codigo java.. ficou bem fácil de entender, bem bacana e tira essa dúvida sua amigo.. qualquer dúvidas, estou a disposição!! http://www.redspark.io/utilizando-o-hibernate-envers-com-spring-mvc/

Answer (score 4):

Se o seu objetivo é receber dados de vários bancos e armazená-los em um banco de dados central, eu sugiro que você utilize um recurso do próprio MySQL, o [Multi-Source Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source.html).

Com indicado neste [site](http://mysqlhighavailability.com/mysql-5-7-6-introducing-multi-source-replication/), um banco de dados MySQL pode agora se tornar **slave** de diversos **masters**:

[image: Gráfico tirado de http://mysqlhighavailability.com/]

Eles disponibilizam alguns tutoriais [aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source-tutorials.html).

Mas [neste site](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/02/mysql-5-7-multi-source-replication/), tudo parece bem mais simples! (Esse link eu achei [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27892956/1579771).)

Comment: Obrigado Daniel
Curti esses tutoriais, vou estudar mais sobre replicação.
As filiais estão usando o mysql 5.5, se eu optar por essa escolha, terei que atualizar todas, ai vou tem um grande problema, tem filiais no brasil todo, macapa, nordeste, sul. E minha idéia era apenas atualizar o JAR da minha aplicação, com os metódos p/ a integração com o WS. Pois mudanças simples, mesmo orientando por telefone, da muito problema.